# Sort a list of a href tags using the contents of a span tag contained within

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I'm having trouble getting a sort function to work correctly. I am dynamically creating a list of `a href` links that I want to sort as they are appended. This is the JQuery code to generate the a hrefs:

```
var matchScoresText='<a href="#breakdownDialog" data-transition="slidefade" class="ui-btn" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" id="cvResults"> <h3>' + //data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop" 
        response.title + 
        '</h3>   <span id="percentageContainer"> ' + response.percentage +
        '%</span></a>';
        $('#resultsList').append(matchScoresText);
```

The `#resultsList`is the div element that the a hrefs are appended to. Once these are added, I am attempting to sort the list by the contents of the `<span>` tag. This is populated by `response.percentage`, which is a number.

```
orderedLinks=$('#resultsList > a').sort(sortByPercentage);
        $('#resultsList').append(orderedLinks);
```

I can't quite get the sort function itself correct. At the moment it looks like this:

```
function sortByPercentage(a, b){
return $('#percentageContainer').text() < $('#percentageContainer').text() ? 1 : -1;
}
```

I suspect this is the problem, but I'm not sure how else to select the contents of `#percentageContainer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `sort` handler function you need to use the values provided by the `a` and `b` parameters which relate to the `span` element within the `a` being iterated over. You also need to convert the value to either int or float, depending on the precision required. Try this:

```
var $orderedLinks = $('#resultsList a').sort(sortByPercentage);
$('#resultsList').append($orderedLinks);

function sortByPercentage(a, b){
    return parseFloat($(a).find('span').text()) - parseFloat($(b).find('span').text());
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9qujzace/)

Comment: This works. Perfect. Thanks very much! Hadn't seen the .find() method before